# how to add autocomplete option to ckeditor dialog input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor 4.3 , jquery-ui autocomplete.

I have ckeditor input element of type html ,

its showing x no. of results are there . but not showing dropdown (autocomplete )

how to add this option in ckeditor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was working .i was behind the dialog box.

Change z-index of autocomplete dropdown

```
open: function(){
    $(this).autocomplete('widget').css('z-index', 10011);
    return false;
},
```

you can check z-index of dialog, by inspect element